# How to update the changes in two different eclipse views programmatically

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have created two different views in RCP. Now I want to the changes done in one eclipse view to be automatically reflected in the other view.

I am completely new to RCP plugin development. Can anyone help me with the code to implement the above requirement?

Comment: See http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4EventSystem/article.html

Comment: @howlger: Hi, i am not supposed to use e4 implementation. Please let me know if you have any other idea

Comment: e4 means Eclipse 4.x which was introduced 5 years ago. But of course, you can implement it without using anything from the Eclipse platform for that.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you use Eclipse 3 platform and, as far as I know, there are three ways of connecting workbench parts (my ref. is "Eclipse Rich Client Platform" second edition p255) :

1) To expose structural changes to other parts use the Selection service :

To register part changes use ISelectionProvider, for instance in your first view :

```
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
  int style = SWT.SINGLE | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL;
  viewer = new TableViewer(parent, style);
  getSite().setSelectionProvider(viewer);
  ...
}
```

To listen to changes (don't forget to unregister listener when no longer needed) use ISelectionListener, for instance in your second view :

```
public class ChaptersView extends ViewPart {
  private TableViewer viewer;
  ISelectionListener listener = new ISelectionListener() {
     public void selectionChanged(IWorkbenchPart part, ISelection sel) {
        if (!(sel instanceof IStructuredSelection))
           return;
        IStructuredSelection ss = (IStructuredSelection) sel;
        Object o = ss.getFirstElement();
        if (o instanceof Book)
           viewer.setInput(ss.size()==1 ? o : null);
     }
  };
  public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
     getSite().getPage().addSelectionListener(listener);
  }
  public void dispose() {
     getSite().getPage().removeSelectionListener(listener);
  }
}
```

These examples come from [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_make_a_view_respond_to_selection_changes_in_another_view%3F).

2) To listen to part events like close, open or hide, use part listeners :

You must somewhere implement IPartListener2 and then add this listener to the parts listeners using the active page of the active workbench window :

```
workbenchWindow().getActivePage().addPartListener(IPartListener2);
```

Don't forget to unregister listener when no longer needed :

```
workbenchWindow().getActivePage().removePartListener(IPartListener2);
```

3) You can implement your own communication mechanism but it will probably introduce a too strong coupling between parts.